# How do I make my page container fit entire browser window?

Tags: css

I would like to make my page container fit the entire browser. So far it fits the entire width, and the top. It does not go all the way to the bottom. There is this little section it is not covering. How do I get it to cover the entire page? (I've
 already tried the suggestions that have been made on other posts ex. body height:100%)

so far this is the CSS:

```
             body{
              background: -webkit-radial-gradient(#F0F0F0,#E8E8E8);
              background: -moz-radial-gradient(#F0F0F0,#E8E8E8);
              background: -ms-radial-gradient(#F0F0F0,#E8E8E8);
              background: -o-radial-gradient(#F0F0F0,#E8E8E8);
              margin: 0 auto;
              font-family: myriad pro, sans-serif;
              font-size:18px;

              }

             .page{
                   min-height: 100%; 
                   height:100%; <!-- if IE -->
                   width: 100%;
                   min-width:100%;


              }
```

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
body { 
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I'd do this both so: `html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; }`